# Having hard time importing JZY3D into my project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jzy3d

I'm new to this library, and i just couldn't import it, and i don't know why.
I'm using intellji. I have downloaded this demo from git hub:
https://github.com/basix86/jzy3d-javafx-demos
to try and understand how it works, and here are the problems:
[image: warnings in the pom.xml]

[image: warnings in the pom.xml]

here is the entire code:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.basix86</groupId>
  <artifactId>chart</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>chart</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
      <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
      <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
      <artifactId>jzy3d-javafx</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Choose a non-SNAPSHOT version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jzy3d

Comment: By the looks of it IDEA just didn't find these Artifacts in the Maven Local and its' indexes.  Try running Maven Sync ("Reload All Maven Projects" from the Maven Tool Window (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html)) and it should resolve successfully.

Comment: I’ll try that and update if worked, tnx